# Append at the end of line using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have already seen other answers trying to solve my problem but I am not able to solve it.

```
#!/bin/bash
s=org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings
g=$(echo $s | sed "s|\.|/|g") 
echo $g
```

I have above script  which returns

```
org/gnome/Terminal/Legacy/Keybindings
```

but I need to append `/` at the end of this so that it becomes

```
org/gnome/Terminal/Legacy/Keybindings/
```

How to extend my sed script for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***sed*** approach:

```
s="org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings"
g=$(echo $s | sed "y|.|/|; s|$|/|")
echo $g
org/gnome/Terminal/Legacy/Keybindings/
```

---

- `y|\.|/|` - translate all dots `.` to slashes `/`

Comment: what is the difference between `s|ToBeReplaced|ReplaceByThis` and `y|ToBeReplaced|ReplaceByThis` in sed

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut, 1) `y/src/dst/` - Transliterate any characters in the pattern space which match any of the source-chars with the corresponding character in dest-chars. 2) `s/regexp/replacement/flags` - the `s` command attempts to match the pattern space against the supplied regular expression regexp; if the match is successful, then that portion of the pattern space which was matched is replaced with replacement.

Comment: thank you Roman, do you have any suggestions for any books where I can learn sed from?

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` for the `y` command, it accepts literal characters. `y|.|/|`. The `y` commands transliterates, matching single characters from `src` and replacing them with characters from `dst`. E.g. `y,abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ,` would change all text to upper-case.

Comment: @GenePavlovsky, that was easy

Answer (score 9):

You don't really need sed for this, if you're using bash.

```
s="org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings"
g=${s//.//}/
```

Read the [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) section of bash man page (`${parameter/pattern/string}`), it also has many other useful things.

With sed, you can also specify multiple expressions, sometimes it is more readable.

```
s="org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings"
g=$(sed -e 'y,.,/,' -e 's,$,/,' <<<$s)
```

Note that with `y` command you don't have to escape the `.`, `y` command accepts literal characters.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
sed 's/\.\|$/\//g'
```

- `|` is the alternation operator.
- `$` will match the end of line.

Demo:

```
%echo org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings|sed 's/\.\|$/\//g'
org/gnome/Terminal/Legacy/Keybindings/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
#!/bin/bash
s=org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings
g=$(echo $s | sed "s|\.|/|g") 
echo $(echo "$g" | sed 's@$@/@')
```

it searches for The end of the line (`$`) and replaces it with a `/`.

`@` is an alternative seperator.

Comment: `@` is not that readable in my opinion, I prefer `,`.

Comment: I prefer @ because it's the only symbol that I never needed in a script except as seperator. @GenePavlovsky

Answer (score 1):

You're doing two things with `sed` here:

1. replacing all the dots with slashes, and
2. adding a slash to the end of line

The first task may be done by the `sed` command `y#.#/#`.  The `y` command is similar to how the `tr` utility works in that it replaces characters from one string to another without involving regular expressions. The three `#` are delimiters for the command (it usually uses `/`, as in `y/A-Z/a-z/` to lowercase all characters in the `A-Z` range), but just like with the `s` command, we may use any delimiter we want.

The second task may be done by replacing the end of line with a slash using `s#$#/#`.

Putting these together, we get

```
sed -e 'y#.#/#' -e 's#$#/#'
```

In your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
s='org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings'
g=$( sed -e 'y#.#/#' -e 's#$#/#' <<<"$s" )
printf '%s\n' "$g"
```

This produces

```
org/gnome/Terminal/Legacy/Keybindings/
```

---

Of course, the slash may be put in by the `printf` and the replacements of the dots with slashes may be done with `tr` too:

```
#!/bin/bash
s='org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings'
g=$( tr '.' '/' <<<"$s" )
printf '%s/\n' "$g"
```

Comment: What is the difference between `sed 's/text1/text2'`, `sed 's:text1:text2'`, `sed 's@text1@text2'`, `sed 's#text1#text2'`, `sed 's|text1|text2'`? Can we use any special symbol we want or do these `/:@#|` have some meaning?

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut All of those contains syntax errors; the last delimiter (`/`, `:`, `@` and `#` respectively) is missing. Apart from that, all are equivalent. You may choose whichever character you want to delimit the `s` command:  `sshellosworlds` will replace `hello` with `world`, as would `s/hello/world/` and `s!hello!world!`. It's allowed to get rid of the "leaning toothpick syndrome": `s/\/var\/log\//\/usr\/var\/log\//` --> `s#/var/log/#/usr/var/log/#`.

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut Just for fun: I looked through the dictionary for words that were `sed` substitution commands. `sentence` would replace `nt` with `nc`, for example.